# Edit Text/HTML Module in Dotnetnuke adds text/P tags

Tags: dotnetnuke-5

Is there any way to prevent the Text/HTML Module in DNN from adding tags (like an initial

when you edit in source view and switch back to display?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh. Apparently a known issue with early versions of the FCKEditor. Some js tweaks available.